# Django, Trying to install older package, "cannot import name email_re"

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to install PennyBlack:

https://github.com/allink/pennyblack

I've done some reading, and it appears that "email_re" was removed from the latest version of Django.

I am VERY new.  I was wondering if anyone could tell me a workaround so that I can get this older package installed?

Answer (score 1):

The most correct way to behave in this situation would be not to use the module that [is not maintained](https://github.com/allink/pennyblack/commits/master) and doesn't support several latest `django` versions. Instead, find an alternative, see [`Django Packages`](https://www.djangopackages.com/).

Another possible solution would be to [fork the project](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo) on `github` and [make it work](https://github.com/allink/pennyblack/search?q=email_re&ref=cmdform) with the version of django you are currently using.

Also see the relevant compatibility [issue](https://github.com/allink/pennyblack/issues/45).

Comment: Just as an additional comment: [Here's](https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/newsletter/) the `Django Packages` page for newsletter packages to help find a replacement.

Comment: @Alex thanks for providing the link to the appropriate djangopackages page.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Again very new.  I found this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/validators/, instead of 'from django.core.validators import email_re', would I do 'from django.core.validators import URLValidator, then replace email_re, with 'validate_email'?

Comment: @brizz yeah, but this is not a direct replacement. Hope [this relevant django commit](https://github.com/django/django/commit/4e2e8f39d19d79a59c2696b2c40cb619a54fa745) that introduced the incompatibility would help.

Comment: how is it not a direct replacement, they don't do the same thing?

Comment: @brizz email_re was just a regular expression, `validate_email` is the `EmailValidator` instance.

Comment: ok, thanks.  I am making progress through this now that I have an idea of what I need to do.  Just curious if you could answer one more question.  getting the error " ImportError pennyblack.module.subscriber: cannot import name editor", tried googling 'cannot import name editor', but not finding anything.  Could you point me in a direction?

Comment: @brizz the project depends on `feincms` which is actively maintained. So, apart from django, you now need to make `pennyblack` work with `feincms` - things can go more complicated. You probably need to find an alternative.

Comment: this is most complete email backend I've seen (in regards to open/click tracking/bounce processing, etc).  and originally was planning on starting from scratch (and am just starting to learn python). ..so plan on sticking with it.

Comment: Let me ask one more thing.  Is there some sort of "tool", or a way to see which individual python file is causing __init.py__ to show an error?  as it stands now when I do python manage.py syncdb, it just lists __init.py__ under the Python26 directory.  If I could narrow it down that would be looads of help.  I'm learning python, and it would be good to get down into some code instead of just 'reading'.  Thanks for your help!!

Comment: @brizz just looking at a traceback usually helps to identify the culprit. You can also try running `python manage.py validate` or make use of static code analysis tools like `pylint` or `pyflakes`..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51219/discussion-between-brizz-and-alecxe)

Comment: actually got it to work!  used pycharm, and just went through and fixed all the errors.  still need to get an actual use of the validate_email, but so happy!  thanks again.